# Open remote location from PowerShell as different user

Tags: powershell, permissions, active-directory

I need to open some remote folder a lot of times, and I usually use `start` in powershell this way

```
start \\myserverXXX\some_hidden_drive$\some_folder
```

Sometimes I need to use an administrator account, and I would expect to be prompted to insert different credential, but i get an error instead. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Use the credential option as follows

```
start \\myserverXXX\some_hidden_drive$\some_folder -Credential $(Get-Credential)
```

This will prompt you to enter different credentials

Comment: I get the same error but credentials are exact.
I didn't specified that I need to log with an Active Directory account. Could this be the problem?

Comment: This is an interesting one. the -Credential option is logically the right way to do this, but it doesn't seem to be passing on the credentials properly. In other Powershell commands there's an -Authentication option to specify the type of authentication to use, but it's not available in Start-Process.

If this doesn't work then I can suggest other way of doing this.

Comment: This is also failing with Access Denied even though the user does have access to the path:
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("\\server\C$","","user",$secpassword,"domain")
Seems to be an issue with the underlying libraries and not isolated to the Powershell Start command

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried mapping a drive using those credentials, then opening it? I don't have a place to test this at the moment.

```
New-PsDrive -Name X -PSProvider Filesystem -Root \\myserverXXX\some_hidden_drive$\some_folder -credential $(get-credential);
Invoke-Item X:
```

Comment: I get this error `The provider does not support the use of credentials.`

Comment: Apparently support for alternate credentials with the `Filesystem` `PSProvider` only came with PS 3.0. There's a [workaround](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/334084/filesystem-provider-should-support-credentials) posted on MS Connect - the net result is the same, map the drive, see if it works for you.